# I need the mysql package 8.0.29, current is 8.0.30

Tags: package-management, mysql, versions

is there a way to download older packages? I would need the one above for a db recovery.

Kind reegards,

Jens

Comment: Recovery procedures such as this is best done using VMs or containers, to avoid polluting a production environment with outdated packages. Link to official [Docker container with v. 8.0.29](https://hub.docker.com/layers/mysql/library/mysql/8.0.29/images/sha256-44f98f4dd825a945d2a6a4b7b2f14127b5d07c5aaa07d9d232c2b58936fb76dc?context=explore).

Comment: Do you need any specific binary that had problems? What happened in your environment? I ask because if you want to populate a database based on a .sql or .dmp file, you can use a different version of the original version, which was running mysql 8.0.29. If you need a specific binary, there is always the possibility to compile a previous version from source, in a VM, for example, if you need a specific binary.